# How can I get all the called method in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I have to extract algorithms from an open source software in order to include these on another software.

As a consequence, I want to know how can I get all the method which are called when I launch one of the algorithm...

I tried to run it in debug mode and navigate step by step and note all the called methods on my board but it's pretty long... I'm using eclipse and I want to know if it can be done automatically.

Comment: Use a Profiler tool, google `profiler java eclipse`

Comment: So you want to copy-paste somebody else's hard work and use it in your project? This is plagiarism, you know.

Comment: Heu it's a university open source code under GNU License so yes I'm going to copy/past some part of it mentionning of course the name of the original authors. It's clearly mentionned " You can redistribute it and/or modify it"

Answer (score 1):

a quick and dirty way to do it, if it's open source, would be to throw an exception in the "deepest" function that's in the call chain, then just catch it and use printStackTrace; or make it a RuntimeException and you don't even have to catch it, just run the program once and the callstack will be printed for you.

Comment: You are assuming that the algorithm is very linear: no loops, no if/then/else... This is not a solution for the general case.  Furthermore you don't explain how to find the "deepest function".

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if can match your needs, but you can use a profiler like VisualVm or JProfiler to trace all the method call executed in you application, [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-visual-vm-jasperreports-server-view-call-traces) you can find an example with visualVm and JasperReport, another way may be define an aspect (aspectJ or spring) to intercept the method call and log it were you want look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/examples-development.html#tracing-using-aspects)